# Partition of $\Bbb R^2$ arising from matrix multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Describe the partition of $\Bbb R^2$ arising from the action, by matrix multiplication, of the subgroup $H=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    a & 1
\end{pmatrix}:a\in\Bbb R\right\}$ of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$.

First of all I don't think I really understand the question itself. Does it means I pick elements of $H$ and apply matrix multiplication to $\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    y
\end{pmatrix}$ where $x,y\in\Bbb R$? I don't know how to describe the partition of a cartesian in terms of matrix multiplication And don't know what partition to describe I am confused. And why is the answer like this:"The lines $x=c$ for $c\neq0$ and the points $(0,b)$"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you multiply the mentioned matrix by $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$, what happens is that $x$ remains constant and $y$ is translated by $ax$. Since $a$ can be any number in $\mathbb R$, and only $y$ will change then all the resulting vectors will end up with
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y+ax\end{bmatrix}$$

We will have one special case which occurs if $x=0$, then we get $$\begin{bmatrix}0\\y+a\cdot 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\y\end{bmatrix}$$
So these will be the isolated points $(0,b)$ in the answer, where $y=b$.

Whenever $x\neq 0$ we will have a parametrized line $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} +a\begin{bmatrix}0\\x\end{bmatrix}$ for the parameter $a$.

Comment: Yes $y$ will become equal to $b$ in the answer in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first prove that indeed $H\le\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, and that we really have a $H$-action on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

- *Subgroup - closure*:
  $\space\begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 \\
  a & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 \\
  b & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}=
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 \\
  a+b & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}\in H$;
- *Subgroup - "closure by inverses"*:
  $\space\begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 \\
  a & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 \\
  -a & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}\in H$;
- *Action - property #0*:
  $\space\begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 \\
  a & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  x \\
  y \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  x \\
  ax+y \\
  \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2
  $
- *Action - property #1*:
  $\space\begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  x \\
  y \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  x \\
  y \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  ,\space\space\forall \begin{pmatrix} 
  x \\
  y \\
  \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^2$
- *Action - property #2*:

$
\space\biggl(\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
b & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\biggr)
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
a+b & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\
(a+b)x+y \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\
ax+bx+y \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\
bx+y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\biggl(
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
b & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}
\biggr)
,\space\space
\forall \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
a & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
b & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\in H, \space\space\forall \begin{pmatrix} 
x \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^2
$

From the general action theory, we know that the "acted upon" set, i.e. here $\mathbb{R}^2$, is *partitioned* into "orbits", given by (here $X$ is the generic point of $\mathbb{R}^2$):

$$O(X)=\{AX, A\in H\}=\biggl\{\begin{pmatrix} 
x \\
ax+y \\
\end{pmatrix}, \space \space a\in \mathbb{R}\biggr\}\tag 1$$

By $(1)$, the orbits by $x=0$ points "don't feel" the action of $H$ (via the parameter $a$): the points of the $y$-axis ($x=0$) constitue *each* a "degenerate" orbit:

$$O(X_{x=0})=O(y)=\biggl\{\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}, \space \space a\in \mathbb{R}\biggr\}=\biggl\{\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}\biggr\}$$

Off $y$-axis points ($x\ne 0$), instead, are moved all along the "vertical" direction by the point $(x,y)$. Summarizing, the partition of $\mathbb{R}^2$ induced by this action is made of single-point orbits (one for each point of the $y$-axis) and "vertical", straight lines for the rest of the real plane.